# Is it possible to use EntityFramework 7 with MySql? With PostGres?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, postgresql

EF7 claims to support lots of providers, but I'm having trouble finding documentation about which ones currently exist. I'm particularly interested in MySQL and Postgres providers.

Comment: At least Npgsql people are working on EF7 for PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

ATM EF7 still under development, currently it only support SQL Server, SQLLite and Azure Table Storage.

Since the code based still not standardized, when it standarlized MySQL (Oracle) will work on the providers.

Answer (score 0):

Another update for the question, EF7 is starting to support PostgreSQL, Please have a try on this below article.

http://druss.co/2015/04/vnext-use-postgresql-fluent-nhibernate-from-asp-net-5-dnx-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Can you point out where the provided link mentions EF? I only see a discussion of FluentNHibernate